# reaction.emoji.name returns a unicode string, how to check if something matches that unicode?

Tags: javascript, node.js, unicode, discord, discord.js

I am using Discord.js for a discord bot, and im trying to make a starboard feature, but I asked for help and they gave me reaction.emoji.name and said it returns a unicode string, I am unsure how to check if the reaction is that speficic unicode character.

My code:

[image]

**I am using a image since back ticks wouldn't work and claimed my code was improperly formatted. Sorry for the inconvenience.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To compare default emoji's to string, find the unicode emoji and use that.

Go into discord and type out the emoji you want to compare for. Preface this with a `\`:
[image: Example of collecting reaction.emoji.name]

Copy the second emoji produced (smaller size and usually differently coloured). Insert this in your code like this:

[image]

Or in raw code:

```
if (reaction.emoji.name === '⭐')
{
```