# Reaction Role with nextcord

Tags: python, discord, nextcord

On my Nextcord bot, I want to add a reaction role system. I've tried this code:

```py
@commands.Cog.listener()
async def on_raw_reaction_add(self, payload):
    message_id = payload.message_id
    if message_id == 930812411097796618:
        guild_id = payload.guild_id
        guild = nextcord.utils.find(lambda g: g.id == guild_id, self.bot.guilds)
        if payload.emoji.name == "tada":
            role = nextcord.utils.get(guild.roles, id=896417683153752104)
        elif payload.emoji.name == "nut_and_bolt":
            role = nextcord.utils.get(guild.roles, id=896417735473528832)
        elif payload.emoji.name == "microphone":
            role = nextcord.utils.get(guild.roles, id=896417789458403368)
        elif payload.emoji.name == "part_alternation_mark":
            role = nextcord.utils.get(guild.roles, id=896417886724313128)
        elif payload.emoji.name == "desktop":
            role = nextcord.utils.get(guild.roles, id=896397761770053682)
        elif payload.emoji.name == "screwdriver":
            role = nextcord.utils.get(guild.roles, id=896397839784083496)
        elif payload.emoji.name == "wrench":
            role = nextcord.utils.get(guild.roles, id=896398445487726613)
        elif payload.emoji.name == "elephant":
            role = nextcord.utils.get(guild.roles, id=922184344238444596)
        elif payload.emoji.name == "gem":
            role = nextcord.utils.get(guild.roles, id=896398489376944138)
        elif payload.emoji.name == "mobile_phone":
            role = nextcord.utils.get(guild.roles, id=896398561179226133)
        elif payload.emoji.name == "bird":
            role = nextcord.utils.get(guild.roles, id=896398605873729547)
        elif payload.emoji.name == "floppy_disk":
            role = nextcord.utils.get(guild.roles, id=896398741605584936)
        elif payload.emoji.name == "hash":
            role = nextcord.utils.get(guild.roles, id=896398802204913664)
        elif payload.emoji.name == "snake":
            role = nextcord.utils.get(guild.roles, id=896398888817283113)
        else:
            channel = self.bot.get_channel(930598926174781460)
            embed = nextcord.Embed(title="An error occured")
            await channel.send(embed=embed)

        if role is not None:
            member = nextcord.utils.find(lambda m: m.id == payload.user_id, guild.members)
            if member is not None:
                await member.add_roles(role)
            else:
                channel = self.bot.get_channel(930598926174781460)
                embed = nextcord.Embed(title="An error occured")
                await channel.send(embed=embed)
        else:
            channel = self.bot.get_channel(930598926174781460)
            embed = nextcord.Embed(title="None")
            await channel.send(embed=embed)
```

I followed [this](https://youtu.be/MgCJG8kkq50) YouTube tutorial (I did changed `discord` for `nextcord`), but it seems to don't work. This is my console after executing the code:

[image: output]

I don't know what does it means, so I can't fix my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that when the payload.emoji.name does not equal any of the ones listed, this code is run:

```
        else:
            channel = self.bot.get_channel(930598926174781460)
            embed = nextcord.Embed(title="An error occured")
            await channel.send(embed=embed)
```

You then try to run the following code, which references the name "role":

```
if role is not None:
```

However, if the payload.emoji.name does not equal any of the ones listed, role does not get bound, and you get an error from trying to use a variable which does not exist.

### Solution

You can solve this by **adding a return statement to the block above**, like so:

```
        else:
            channel = self.bot.get_channel(930598926174781460)
            embed = nextcord.Embed(title="An error occured")
            await channel.send(embed=embed)
            return
```

This will stop the function when no role is set before trying to use role, so it should resolve the error.

You also need to edit the names of the emojis, or else payload.emoji.name will not match any of them, as they use the unicode version of the emoji and not discord's name for the emoji.

**For example, instead of using "nut_and_bolt", you should use "" instead.**
[payload.emoji.name](https://nextcord.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#nextcord.PartialEmoji.name)

[How to get unicode emoji from emoji name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49619688/reaction-emoji-name-returns-a-unicode-string-how-to-check-if-something-matches)

---

As an aside, you can improve your code by using

```
role = guild.get_role(role_id=your_role_id)
```

instead of

```
role = nextcord.utils.get(guild.roles, id=your_role_id)
```

Likewise, you can use

```
member = guild.get_member(user_id=payload.user_id)
```

instead of

```
member = nextcord.utils.find(lambda m: m.id == payload.user_id, guild.members)
```

and finally,

```
guild = self.bot.get_guild(id=payload.guild_id)
```

instead of

```
guild = nextcord.utils.find(lambda g: g.id == guild_id, self.bot.guilds)
```

Comment: so how do I fix it?

Comment: @W1L7 I edited the answer to make it more clear

Comment: Hello! I've tried to do what you did, but for some reason, it juste sending "none".

Comment: That matches the behaviour which was happening before, can you try printing payload.emoji.name before
 `if payload.emoji.name == "tada":`

Comment: https://youtu.be/h7Eqs0EESzo

Comment: I added more info to the solution, you can find the unicode version of every emoji on a website like this: https://emojipedia.org/

Comment: Well, it didn't worked. It's just returning none

Comment: @W1L7 did you change all of them to unicode?

Comment: yes i did. Can you add me on discord? It would be easier to communicate. My discord is W1L7 </♪>#9944